# Creating a global "null" struct for re-use in C program?

Tags: objective-c, c, struct, global

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  I have a struct that is used heavily through my program.

```
typedef struct _MyStruct {
  // ... handful of non-trivial fields ...
} MyStruct;
```

I expect (read, intend) for lots of parts of the program to return one of these structs, but many of them should be able to return a "null" struct, which is a singleton/global.  The exact use case is for the implementing function to say "I can't find what you asked me to return".

I assumed this would be a simple case of defining a variable in a header file, and initializing it in the .c file.

```
// MyStruct.h

// ... Snip ...

MyStruct NotFoundStruct;
```

-

```
// MyStruct.c

NotFoundStruct.x = 0;
NotFoundStruct.y = 0;
// etc etc
```

But the compiler complains that the initialization is not constant.

Since I don't care about what this global actually references in memory, I only care that everything uses the same global, I tried just removing the initialization and simply leaving the definition in the header.

But when I do this:

```
MyStruct thing = give_me_a_struct(some_input);
if (thing == NotFoundStruct) {
  // ... do something special
}
```

Th compiler complains that the operands to the binary operator "==" (or "!=") are invalid.

How does one define such as globally re-usable (always the same memory address) struct?

Comment: MyStruct NotFoundStruct = {0}; // perhaps

Comment: Why not `MyStruct* thing = give_me_a_struct(some_input);` ?

Comment: Switching all of this code to use pointer would be a huge and painful refactoring exercise.  I can do it, but I'd rather not have to rewrite that much code purely to allow my app to determine if a function returned a "not found" value or not.

Comment: Well.. By returning a `MyStruct` you return a copy of your sentinel. The information about its address is lost. If you want to compare addresses, return an address.

Comment: I'd say it's design error. The only thing you could do to avoid refractoring is to add an `empty` flag to your structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// MyStruct.h

typedef struct _MyStruct {
  // fields
} MyStruct;

extern MyStruct NotFoundStruct;

// MyStruct.c

#include "my_struct.h"
MyStruct NotFoundStruct = {0};
```

But since you can't use the `==` operator, you will have to find another way to distinguish it.  One (not ideal) way is to have a `bool` flag reserved to indicate validity.  That way, only that must be checked to determine if it's a valid instance.

But I think you should consider James's proposed solution instead

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. That's exactly what I've got now, and it's still complaining about "invalid binary operands" when I try to compare against it.  Looks like I'm gonna have to go down the pointers route, but I've already got a complex situation in this code with pointers and it seems a shame to complicate the code further purely so I can use NULL.

Comment: @d11wtq, as I (and James) said, you can't use relational operators to compare the whole struct.  That's why I suggested the validity flag.

Comment: Thanks, yeah.  The context of this code is actually part of an objective-C app, where I'm optimzing out some heavy objective-C object allocations and replacing them with simple structs to reduce heap memory allocation overhead and to reduce the memory footprint generally.  Since my struct happens to contain an NSRange, I can in theory just use NSNotFound for the range.location value (like Apple does) and check that instead.  It just means memory overhead is starting to go upward once again :(

Comment: @d11, if you already have a range, how does that increase your memory?  `NSNotFound` is just a constant equal to `NSIntegerMax`.

Comment: Using the flag on the struct works well, thanks :)  I was able to just use an existing member of the struct for this.

Answer (score 10):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but it won't fit in a comment...

If you have a function that may need to return something or return nothing, there are several options that are better than returning a "null struct" or "sentinel struct," especially since structs are not equality comparable in C.

One option is to return a pointer, so that you can actually return `NULL` to indicate that you are really returning nothing; this has the disadvantage of having significant memory management implications, namely who owns the pointer? and do you have to create an object on the heap that doesn't already exist on the heap to do this?

A better option is to take a pointer to a struct as an "out" parameter, use that pointer to store the actual result, then return an `int` status code indicating success or failure (or a `bool` if you have a C99 compiler).  This would look something like:

```
int give_me_a_struct(MyStruct*);

MyStruct result;
if (give_me_a_struct(&result)) {
    //  yay!  we got a result!
}
else {
    //  boo!  we didn't get a result!
}
```

If `give_me_a_struct` returns zero, it indicates that it did not find the result and the `result` object was not populated.  If it returns nonzero, it indicates that it did find the result and the `result` object was populated.

Comment: Almost exactly what I was about to say :)

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't allow global non-const assignments. So you must do this in a function:

```
void init() {
   NotFoundStruct.x = 0;
   NotFoundStruct.y = 0;
}
```

As for the comparison, C doesn't know how to apply a `==` operator to a struct. You can overload (redefine) the operator in C++, but not in C.

So to see if a return value is empty, your options are to

1. Have each function return a boolean value to indicate found or not, and return the struct's values via pointers through the argument list. (eg. `bool found = give_me_a_struct(some_input, &thing);`)
2. Return a pointer to a struct, which can be NULL if nothing exists. (eg. `MyStruct* thing = give_me_a_struct(some_input);`)
3. Add an additional field to the struct that indicates whether the object is valid.

The third option is the most generic for other cases, but requires more data to be stored. The best bet for your specific question is the first option.

Answer (score -1):

In the header:

```
// Structure definition then
extern MyStruct myStruct;
```

In the .c that contains global data

```
struct MyStruct myStruct
{
   initialize field 1,
   initialize field 2,
   // etc...
};
```

Comment: OK lazy and spineless, if you're gonna vote it down, say why...  This concisely tells the guy what to do as he asks.  No fluff, no filler.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be obvious that your code is wrong.  You can't initialize `struct` members like that in C.